# How can I make an Image-based Rosace?

Tags: javascript, z-index, mask

I am making a function in **Javascript** that generates rosace with images and display it on the **browser**.

In the example below, I replaced images with Div Elements with random colors.

Ultimately, one image will be repeated to **create a pattern**.

I need the number and size of image/div to be flexible since it's producing different pattern.

Here is what I have :

```
    function drawRosace(number, size) {
        let offset = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
          const circle = document.createElement('div');
          circle.style.position = 'absolute';
          circle.style.top = '50%';
          circle.style.left = '50%';
          circle.style.borderRadius = '50%';
          circle.style.width = size + 'px';
          circle.style.height = size + 'px';
          circle.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
          circle.style.transformOrigin = 'left center';
          circle.style.transform = 'rotate(' + offset + 'deg)';
          document.body.appendChild(circle);
          offset += (360 / number);
        }
    }

    function getRandomColor() {
        let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        let color = '#';
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }

    drawRosace(8, 50);
```

As you can see, the last div is above all the other circles.

> **My question is** : How can I make it so that it loops over and we don't see where it begins ?

Thanks for your help.

[image: Rosace_8_wrong]
[image: Rosace_8]

Comment: I would set a `z-index` property to each circle to get desired result. I can't imagine how would such object look like (seems like you will always have a full circle somewhere)

Comment: I don't think you can get the output that you want due to the way stacking contexts work.  I even tried to get the pattern you are trying for with CSS transforms where everything is titled slightly in such a way that they would look like flower petals, but since each gets it's on stacking context, the one that gets drawn last still overlaps everything else.  There is no way to tell CSS to perform a more complex depth test to get the desired effect.